# rsync how to include files that are excluded

Tags: rsync

I'm trying to set up an rsync that excludes all `.*` files except for `.htaccess` but unfortunately, this doesn't work:

```
rsync -avP --exclude=".*" --include="./.htaccess" ./. user@server:/dir
```

Is it possible to somehow exclude general exclude rules?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just reverse the order of your arguments:

```
rsync -avP --include="./.htaccess" --exclude=".*" ./. user@server:/dir
```

The first matching pattern wins. For more information, see the FILTER RULES section of the `rsync(1)` manpage.

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync for reference.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work, but dropping the "./" in front of "./.htaccess" did.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following

```
find . -type f -name ".*" |grep -v .htaccess > dotfiles
```

then use

```
rsync --avP --exclude-from=dotfiles ./. user@server:/dir
```